# How to modify the characters in a char array

Tags: arrays, c

My intention was to use the command line to read input and store it into an array and modify the characters of the array. If the character is '1', then turn it into '0', vice versa. I successfully store the input into an array, yet failed to modify the characters of the array. If I put 0000000000000000000000000000000(32bits) into my program, the output doesn't change.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *a = argv[argc-1];
    char arr[33];

    size_t length = strlen(a);
    for(size_t i=0;i<length;i++) {
        arr[i]=a[i];
    }
    for(int j=0; j<32;j++) {
        if(arr[j]=='0') {
            arr[j]='1';
        }
        if(arr[j]=='1') {
            arr[j]='0';
        }
    }
    for(int k=0;k<32;k++) {
        printf("%c",arr[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: don't put line numbers. We can't copy paste in our editor and compile it.

Comment: `if(arr[j]=='1')` -> `else if (arr[j]=='1')`. Otherwise the first `if` changes from 0 to 1 and the second `if` will then change it back from 1 to 0! Suggest you do basic debugging to understand the program - run it in a debugger and/or add debug print statements to trace the program execution.

Comment: `j<32`, `k<32;` you access uninitialized  data in `arr`.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *If I put 0000000000000000000000000000000(32bits) into my program, the output doesn't change.*

First of all, your program is not processing bits of input but it is processing the characters of input you are passing as command line argument to your program. If you want to process the bits of input, to start with, read about bitwise operators first.

Look at this `for` loop:

```
    for(int j=0; j<32;j++) {
        if(arr[j]=='0') {
            arr[j]='1';
        }
        if(arr[j]=='1') {
            arr[j]='0';
        }
    }
```

If current processing `arr` element value is `'0'`, the second `if` condition in the `for` loop body will nullify the effect of first `if` condition on that `arr` element i.e. the `arr` element value will be unchanged and if the current processing `arr` element value is `'1'` than it will be set to `'0'`. So, after the loop, all the elements of array `arr`, which have original value as either `'1'` or `'0'`, will set to `'0'` and that's the flaw in your logic.

Few suggestions:

If program is supposed to receive command line argument('s), make sure to put check on `argc` value. In your case, user is supposed to pass the string comprised of `'0'`<sup>s</sup> and `'1'`<sup>s</sup>, so you should check on `argc` value, something like:

```
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf ("Usage: <exe_name> <string_of_0s_and_1s>\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

Since, you do not have check on `argc` value in your program, if user do not pass any string from command line, the value of `argc` may be `1` and ,in this case, `argv[argc-1]` (or `argv[0]`) represents the program name or if the program name is not available from the host environment than `argv[0][0]` will be the null character. If `argv[0]` represents program name whose length is greater than `32` characters then your program will land up in undefined behaviour territory because there is no check on whether the command line input string length is <= `32` characters while copying it to `arr` buffer.

Since you are copying the input to `char` array (not as string) declare `arr` as array of `32` characters and not `33` characters. Looks like, you have assumed the input will be of size <= `32` characters. There is no problem with this assumption as long as program is running in a controlled environment where you are taking care of it. But still, by chance, if input string length is > `32` characters then your program behaviour will be undefined as it will end up processing array `arr` beyond it's size. You should add a check on length of input string as well:

```
    if (length > 32) {
        printf ("Input string length is >= 33 character.\n" \
                "The permitted input string length is <= 32 characters.\nExiting..\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

If you want the input string to be of exact `32` characters, you can add check `if (length != 32)`.

While copying the string, you can also add check on the characters of input string and if it contain character other than `'1'` and `'0'` then throw error message and exit.

Putting these altogether :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *a = NULL;
    char arr[32];

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf ("Usage: <exe_name> <string_of_0s_and_1s>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    a = argv[argc-1];

    size_t length = strlen(a);

    if (length > 32) {
        printf ("Input string length is > 32 characters.\n" \
                "The permitted input string length is <= 32 characters.\nExiting..\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if ((a[i] != '1') && (a[i] != '0')) {
            printf ("Found a character other than characters '1' and '0' in the input string.\n" \
                    "The input string should comprised of characters `1' and '0' only.\nExiting..");
            return 1;
        }
            
        arr[i] = a[i];
    }

    for (size_t j = 0; j < length; j++) {
        if (arr[j] == '0') {
            arr[j] = '1';
        } else {
            arr[j] = '0';
        }
    }

    for (size_t k = 0; k < length; k++) {
        printf ("%c", arr[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy string you need to copy null character as well.

```
size_t length = strlen(a);
 14 for(size_t i=0;i<=length;i++){
 15     arr[i]=a[i];
```

But you do not need to traverse the string twice

```
size_t i=0;
while((arr[i]=a[i])) i++;
```

Your if is wrong. It should be

```
   if(arr[j]=='0') arr[j]='1';
   else arr[j]='0';
```

Answer (score 0):

you forget to give an else if condition in this part of the code.

```
for(int j=0; j<32;j++) {
        if(arr[j]=='0') {
            arr[j]='1';
        }
        else if(arr[j]=='1') {   //This part should be else if
            arr[j]='0';
        }
}
```

In your code for the value of `0` it changed to `1`. But for another `if` condition the value changed to `0` again.